# In jQuery, is there a way to manually propagate an event onto a DOM object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the mouseenter is coded such that it propagates mouseover to all the elements within the DOM that it is bound to.

So, like the question states, is there a way to manually apply this propagation to other elements that are separate from the DOM, which I bound the mouseenter event to.

The function, $.stopPropagation(), stops the propagation but is there an applyPropagationTo like function?

**Here is the scenario:**

Say I have a div, class=divCON. I have a absolute positioned div appended to the body, called divHOV, which is hid. When I mouseenter divCON, divHOV becomes visible and follows my mouse when I am within divCON.

I want it so that when my mouse is moving within divCON, the mouse tends to enter divHOV if the browser is slow to reposition the divHOV while moving the mouse. I want it so that I can propagate divHOV's mouseenter onto divCON so that a mouseleave event is not trigger when I go on divHOV.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuxcR/

Note how when the mouse enters divHOV, it mouseleaves the divCON. I want it so that when it does not mouseleave divCON when I enter divHOV.

Comment: How do you bind an event to an element that's not in the DOM, or rather how are you binding `mouseenter`?

Comment: Could you do `$obj.trigger('mouseover')`?

Comment: @Rocket: or just `$obj.mouseover()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuxcR/1/**

Here's the desired code. See the comments and bottom for explanation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $divCON = $(".divCON");
    $divCON.bind("mouseenter", function() {

        //Cancel if this function has already run (so, if the next element
        //  has class divHOV
        if($(this).next().hasClass('divHOV')) return;
        $divHOV = $("<div class='divHOV'></div>");
        $divHOV.mousemove(function(ev){
            var offset = $divCON.offset();

            var height = $divCON.height();
            var width = $divCON.width();

            var left = offset.left;
            var top = offset.top;

            var bottom = top + height;
            var right = left + width;

            // If the mouse coordinates are within the box
            if(ev.pageX >= left && ev.pageX <= right &&
               ev.pageY >= top && ev.pageY <= bottom){

                //Trigger move.
                $divHOV.css({'top': ev.pageY - 3 + 'px', 'left': ev.pageX + 3 + 'px'});
            }
        });
        $(this).after($divHOV);
    });
    $divCON.bind("mousemove",function(e) {
        $(".divHOV").css({'top': e.pageY - 3 + 'px', 'left': e.pageX + 3 + 'px'});
    });
});
```

When the user enters `.divCON` for the first time, `.divHOV` is added. When moving the mouse (see bottom), `divHOV` is positioned again. Once the mouse enters `.divHOV`, the coordinates are calculated again IF the mouse is within the box of `divCON`.

When the mouse enters `.divCON` again, the function immediately returns, because `.divHOV` already exists: `if($(this).next().hasClass('divHOV')) return;`.

Comment: hey thanks a lot, so Im guessing this is the only solution then. Also, if divCON resizes when the mouse is inside it, when should I recalculate the dimensions, because doing that in the mousemove is too intensive?

Comment: I've already thought about that. If the width/height of `.divCON` are fixed, it's safe to move the definition outside the `mousemove` event, or even outside the `mouseenter` event. Keeping the the calculations inside the `mousemove` event doesn't do any harm though, because the `divHOV` should immediately be positioned again when the mouse enters `divHOV`.